# Whats is efficient database design in sqlite when I only need to insert and retrieve smallest entry in an integer column?

Tags: sql, database, sqlite, heap

Basically I need a **min-heap** functionality with sqlite as my data storage.
Lets say I need a table with 2 columns.
1st is unique ids and
2nd is integer value.
I always need the the id with smallest integer value.

Any suggestions ??

Comment: Which programming language? Maybe you can just use code to do this. Consider creating Heap structure instead. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6y3edk6s%28VS.80%29.aspx

Comment: Integers are inserted in random(unsorted) order.

Comment: My application needs this data over multiple runs. Hence, I need to back it up on hard disk. So, ultimately I have to store it in database in some way. I want it to be such that recreating heap is efficient from database.

Comment: Also data size is large. So, I would prefer if everything happens at database level with no memory wasted. But, a middle way where database and memory both share some load is acceptable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get that for free on indexed columns

```
  CREATE TABLE table(
     one INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
     two INTEGER
  );
  CREATE INDEX table_two ON table(two);

  INSERT ...

  SELECT MIN(two) FROM table;
```

Comment: Does that mean retrieving minimum from indexed column has constant time complexity ??

Comment: @Rohit, practically constant. DB indexes are usually B+ trees with rather wide branches

Comment: One more thing.. Is there anything called sorted indexes? Are rows sorted on primary index ?

Comment: Read about architecture, indexes are trees (so yes, they are 'sorted') with pointers back to data, rows are not necessary in any order on the disk (keeping them sorted would kill update performance and improve only certain queries; RDBM systems try to perform equally well for various queries). In reality primary key/index is what might get used by the system as criteria for order of sequential writes (usually you can override this by specifying clustering index, but SQLite does not seem to support this).

Comment: Also, do realize that the order of the records on the disk benefits only one specific sort order and only on queries that select a lot of sequential records (which is going to be slow anyway).